# Selecting rows on Unique Pairs of columns from mysql Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, distinct

I have a Table `table` .

Now this has three columns `table_id`,`content_id`,`content_type`

What i want is to SELECT rows based on unique pairs of columns.

Say For example i have rows like this-->

```
id|content_id|content_type|

1   1          shirt
2   1          trouser
3   4          skirt
4   4          shirt
5   3          trouser
6   5          jeans
7   1          trouser
8   5          jeans
```

I want a query which **selects** Rows with id->**1,2,3,4,5,6.**

Rows with id->**7,8** are not to be selected

Therefore it concludes that i **dont** want to select **complete Duplicates** of Rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self join to pick a minimum row per group

```
select t.* from 
test t
join (
      select min(id) id ,content_id,content_type
      from test
      group by content_id,content_type
   ) t1
on(t.id = t1.id 
   and t.content_id = t1.content_id 
   and t.content_type = t1.content_type)
```

[**`Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b4f3d/2)

or if there are only these 3 columns in your table then you can simply use `min()`

```
select min(id) id ,content_id,content_type
from test
group by content_id,content_type
```

[**`Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b4f3d/3)

Answer (score 0):

**This is mysql-specific** : If you use the GROUP BY function without using aggregate functions, the group by clause will behave as distinct, and pick up the first distinct row.

```
select id, content_id, content_type from test group by content_id, content_type order by id
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b4f3d/7/0)

Comment: You can go with @Khalid's solution then, and alter it to use max() instead of min().